# How to invoke method, using reflection, on instantiated object?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have some base objects "Car", "dog", "cat" they implement an interface "IGWUIElement". I have a list of these interfaces: List myList.

At runtime I loop through the list of my elements and by examining the name of the class (using reflection) i need to populate their properties - which are not a part of the interface). I have an xml document descripting the propeties and the value i should assign to them. Here is my interface instantiation.

```
IGWUIElement newUIElement = (IGWUIElement)Activator.CreateInstance(result);
```

How do I go about invoking the properties from their name with a particular value (Please note datatypes are limited to int and string). Each object have different properties.

Hope this makes sense...

/H4mm3r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **PropertyInfo.SetValue()**

```
PropertyInfo piInstance = typeof(IGWUIElement).GetProperty("property_name");
piInstance.SetValue(newUIElement, value, null);
```

More on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You can do this like so:

```
IGWUIElement element = myList[0];

// Set a string property
element.GetType().InvokeMember("SomeStringProperty", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty, Type.DefaultBinder, element, "The String Value");

// Set an int property
element.GetType().InvokeMember("SomeIntProperty", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty, Type.DefaultBinder, element, 3);
```